# Uknown property error in vf page while accessing wrapper class object

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

**Controller Class --> wrapperClassController**

```
public class wrapperClassController 

{
public wrapperClassController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

public List<wrapperContact> con;

public Contact cont;

public void setWrapperContact(List<wrapperContact> wc)
{ 
con= wc; }

public List<wrapperContact> getWrapperContact()
{
return con;
}

public List<wrapperContact> getContacts()
{
if(con == null)
{
con = new List<wrapperContact>();
for(Contact c : [select Id,Name,Email,Phone from Contact limit 10])
{
con.add(new wrapperContact(c));
}
}
return con;
}


public PageReference processSelected()
{
 List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

 for(wrapperContact cCon: getContacts()) {
 if(cCon.selected == true) {
 selectedContacts.add(cCon.cont);
}}

System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
for(Contact selcon: selectedContacts) {
system.debug(selcon);
con=null;
}
return null;
}

public class wrapperContact
{
public Contact cont;
public Boolean selected;

public void setContact(Contact c)
{cont = c;}

public Contact getContact()
{return cont;}

public void setselected(Boolean s)
{ selected = s;}

public Boolean getselected()
{ return selected;}

public wrapperContact(Contact c)
{ cont = c; selected = false ; }
}
}
```

**VF Page :-**

```
<apex:page StandardController="Contact" extensions="wrapperClassController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <!-- In our table we are displaying the cContact records -->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
                <apex:column >
                    <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" />
                </apex:column>
                <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
                <apex:column value="{!c.cont.Name}" />

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In the above vf page, i am trying to access wrapper class object in column value but when i do i am getting     Error: Unknown property 'wrapperClassController.wrapperContact.cont'
but my getter method is public only ..dunno why i am getting this unknown property error ?

Thanks in advance,

Dinesh Kumar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for the VF page to access the wrapper class properties you need to define the getter and setters:

```
public class wrapperContact
{
public Contact cont {get;set;}
public Boolean selected {get;set;}

}
```

or use the defined getter methods:

```
c.Contact.Name
```

Comment: He defined the getters/setters in the `wrapperContact` class : `public void setContact(Contact c)
{cont = c;}

public Contact getContact()
{return cont;}`

Comment: @SF_user - Yes, but he is using the property `c.cont` in the vf page and there is no getter for `cont` in the wrapper. he would have to use `c.Contact` as in my answer

Comment: Ah yes, for the `cont` variable, you're right !